# Mongo insert script too slow when querying and looping through large collections

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

i am relatively new to mongo ,so apologies if question is vague in any sorts.
i have a script that i am using and it works well for smaller collections (upto 10k) and runs pretty quick. however it starts to slow down to a snails pace when using it with bigger collections(1M + ). any suggestions on tuning it to make it run faster?

this is what i am using.

```
use DB1;
//collect all color id’s
var list = db.collection1.find({}, { color_Id: 1 }).map(function (collection1) { return collection1.color_Id; })
//get all matching docs using the list above where color id matches p_color_id
var documents = db.collection2.find({ p_color_Id: { $in: list } })
use DB2;
//insert those matching docs into a another collection in a different DB
documents.forEach(function (doc) { db.newCollection.insert(doc) })
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [initializeUnorderedBulkOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/) in order to achieve updating large documents faster like as follows:

```
use DB1;

const list = db.collection1.find({}, { color_Id: 1, _id: 0 }); //Info: It will provide you only color_Id

use DB2;

//Info: Here you're assigning the initializeUnorderedBulkOp
let bulkInsertIntoNewCollection = db.newCollection.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

//Info: Once you find the matching docs you can insert those into another collection in a different DB
//Note: You are just capturing here and not saving
db.collection2.find({ p_color_Id: { $in: list }}).forEach((doc) => bulkInsertIntoNewCollection.insert(doc))

//Info: execute() will save the file all at once.
bulkInsertIntoNewCollection.execute()
```

Let me know if it helped or if you have any doubts, Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it ran into some errors below.
also i have a question on order. the $in query needs to run on Db1 , the way you have listed above will run it against db2 because the $in is run after switching to Db2 instead of Db1. 
either way, i rearranged the order and it still gives the same error below.
```
TypeError: redeclaration of const list :
@(shell):1:7
TypeError: redeclaration of let bulkInsertIntoNewCollection :
@(shell):1:5
 [js] Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "$in needs an array"

Comment: on a second note, i just added the "initializeUnorderedBulkOp" in my script right before the the insert and the script worked and runs better than before. i accidentally used the largest collection in the db instead of trying it on a medium size collection first.
will update back once its done ,so far it looks like its inserting 1000+ records/min on average , not sure if thats the best it can do

Comment: i could only get it to do partial insert before it failed again and somehow it fails after 46k records in multiple tries with the error below.
"errmsg" : "Cursor not found (namespace: 'db.collection', id: 8658831941201964035).",

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error?

Comment: checkout the error below.

2021-07-13T21:37:34.507-0700 E QUERY    [js] Error: getMore command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Cursor not found (namespace: 'db2.newCollection', id: 7194522094652454181).",
 "code" : 43,
 "codeName" : "CursorNotFound",
 "operationTime" : Timestamp(1626237454, 20),
 "$clusterTime" : {
  "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1626237454, 20),
  "signature" : {
   "hash" : BinData(0,"tmYWhC0jaJDSHyXE36ALvUl4T4o="),
   "keyId" : NumberLong("6945635001568329729")
  }
 }

Comment: so upon further research , i found out the mongo connection timesout after 10 mins.
thats why it stops at 46K records give or take.
will try and use the cursor timeout functions and see if it helps.
this is something im doing on the side, so not something im actively working on.
please be mindful if i go without replying back for a day or so
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/